# Create a table of todos

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

I'm working out notes from a meeting in LateX. During the meeting I write down so called "todo's" (not to confuse with the `todo` package). I use my own command TD to simplify my layout, it basicly comes down to this :

```
\newcommand{\TD}[2]{ToDo \textbf{#1} : #2 }
```

Where`#1` is the persons name, and `#2`  what he or she has to do. At the end of my file I want to generate a complete list of all the ToDo's that accumulated along the notes, a bit like a list of symbols for instance. How can I make this ? If possible I want to list them by person, and then use subitems to list all their todos.

Thank you very much

Comment: If my solution fits you needs consider to accept it please

Answer (score 5):

**Improved code with 'grouping' of persons and hyperlinks (if needed)**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{morewrites}

\newcounter{dummycounter}
\newcounter{personposition}
\newtotcounter{personcounter}

\makeatletter
\def\latex@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@input{\jobname.#1}%
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\persontoctext[1]{%
  {%
    \addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
    \noindent\itshape#1%
  }%
}


\newcommand{\NoNamePerson}{Unknown}
\newcommand{\listoftodosname}{List of persons who should do something}





\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__todotoc_personnames_seq



\NewDocumentCommand{\AddPersonName}{mm}{%
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_tl {%
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {\NoNamePerson}
  }{%
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {#1}
  }
  \tl_set_eq:NN  \l_tmpa_tl  \l_tmpb_tl % Copy the 'real name'
  \seq_if_in:NVTF \l__todotoc_personnames_seq {\l_tmpa_tl} {
    \setcounter{dummycounter}{0}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__todotoc_personnames_seq {%
      \stepcounter{dummycounter}%
      \str_if_eq_x:nnT {##1} {\l_tmpa_tl} {% 
        \setcounter{personposition}{\number\value{dummycounter}}
        \seq_map_break: % Break out, we've found the number
      }
    }% End of mapping
  }{%
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__todotoc_personnames_seq {\l_tmpa_tl}
    \stepcounter{personcounter}%
    \setcounter{personposition}{\number\value{personcounter}}% 
    \addtocontents{\arabic{personposition}todo}{\persontoctext{\l_tmpa_tl}}%
  }
  \seq_remove_duplicates:N \l__todotoc_personnames_seq
  \addcontentsline{\arabic{personposition}todo}{section}{#2}%
}


\ExplSyntaxOff




\newcommand{\TD}[2]{%
  \phantomsection%
  \marginnote{ToDo \textbf{#1} : #2}%
  \AddPersonName{#1}{#2}% Adding the name to the list
}

\newcommand{\listoftodos}{%
  \section*{\listoftodosname}
  \setcounter{dummycounter}{0}%
  % Now get all the person specific toc files
  \loop 
  \ifnum\value{dummycounter} < \numexpr\totvalue{personcounter}+1
  \stepcounter{dummycounter}%
  \latex@starttoc{\@arabic\c@dummycounter todo}%
  \repeat%
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{blindtext} % Just to produce text
\usepackage{hyperref}
\providecommand{\phantomsection} % If hyperref is not used!



\begin{document}
\listoftodos

\clearpage

\blindtext[2]
\TD{Groucho}{Slap Harpo}
\blindtext[5]
\TD{}{Improve this document}
\blindtext[2]
\TD{Harpo}{Slap Chico}
\blindtext[5]
\TD{Chico}{Slap Gummo}
\blindtext[5]
\TD{Gummo}{Slap Zeppo}
\blindtext[5]
\TD{Zeppo}{Slap Groucho properly until he will slap Harpo properly and that one will slap Chico}
\blindtext[5]
\TD{Groucho}{Smoke a cigar}
\blindtext[5]
\TD{}{Improve this code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the superquick answer ! but I might have been a bit unclear in my question. I write down todos's as my notes go, at the moment they were decided in the meeting, and what I am actually looking for is a code that generates a kind of summary of all the todo's, just like this one, but I want to avoid copying them all maually in the table, there are like 30 of them and I'll have to do this every week.

Comment: @Libel8: What manual copying? Call the `\TD` command and it is added automatically to the table?

Comment: Oh ok I don't fully understand the code then, my bad ! I'll try it out and play with it to see how it works, Thanks !

Comment: Oh, whoops, I get it now, I missed the end of the code ^^'

Comment: @Libel8: Alright ;-) I leave the design of the `list` to you, especially the formatting of entries, which is done by `\persontoctext` and `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: Have tried it out. I cannot figure out why \TD do not add anything to the list. I get notes at the margins, but the list stays clear. Using \TD{}{Something}